# If statement throws TemplateSyntaxError Invalid block tag on line 127: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make a django app, but I am encountering the following error:

> Exception Type:   TemplateSyntaxError Exception Value:     Invalid block
>   tag on line 127: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget
>   to register or load this tag?

I have reviewed the code, and can not find any typos in my template file, but the template loads normally without the following lines:

```
    {% endif %} {% for i in listings.paginator.page_range %} {% if
listings.number == i %}
    <li class="page-item active">
        <a class="page-link">{{ i }}</a>
    </li>
 {% else %}
    <li class="page-item">
       <a href="?page={{ i }}" class="page-link">{{ i }}</a>
    </li>
 {% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

My entire code for the app is in this github repo in the listings folder: 
https://github.com/twheelertech/btre_project

My code for the template in question is here:
https://github.com/twheelertech/btre_project/blob/master/templates/listings/listings.html

I have checked models.py and views.py in the listings app, but they seem to be formatted correctly.

I am using windows 10, python 3.7.3, django 2.2.6

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Note: The indentation in the code above did not copy over well. I put it in the approx right shape.

Comment: you're sure, the the link to github shows exactly the template file, that you're having problems with?

in line 119 there is no `else` statement.

General advice. as you use git, be sure you committed everything and the reduce the templates to the bare minimum, that still produces the error.

I'm sure the problem will be almost self explaining then.

you can even remove the html if you want to. You just want to keep the `{% ... %}` statements to see whether the templating engine fails.

Comment: I didn't use django templating for quite some time, but I though you need spaces after `{%` and before `%}`m but I see a line like this `{%endfor%}`

Comment: Thanks,  in the github repo the tag is on line 127 instead of 119.  As i shifted around the code trying to fix it i threw the line 119 error and 127 error.  Nothing really changed between the two line spacings.  The issue was multi-line tags as mentioned below.

Comment: As you see it is really important to post exactly what failed and not make any assumptions. The code snippet in your question doesn't even contain the multi-line tag in question. The git repository doesn't match your error description.

This made it unnecessarily difficult to analyze and reproduce the issue.

It makes the question also less useful for the archives people who search the question / similar issues.

Perhaps you could fix the line number in the question and change the code snippet to something containing the problem?

Comment: I modified the tag to contain the error. Thanks.

Comment: thanks Tony. Well appreciated, that you spent time after having found the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Django does not support multi-line tags](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8652), your issue is that your initial "if" tag has a new line in the middle of it

```
{% endif %} {% for i in listings.paginator.page_range %} {% if
listings.number == i %}
```

Try keeping each tag on one line and having one tag per line

```
{% for foo in bar %}
    {% if foo.baz %}
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue.  An auto-formatter for html called 'prettier' in vscode was causing the issue.